# Why does values query set not match model attributes

Tags: django

Using django 1.7, python 3.4, and postgres 9.4.

When i query a model's attribute directly it returns the proper value.
When i query the same model using .values(), it returns improper value.

For example:

```
>>>bomitem = self.itemproduction.billOfMaterials()
>>>for x in bomitem:
>>>    x.ratio
>>>>50
>>>>20
>>>>bomitem.values('ratio')
>>>>[{'ratio': 5}, {'ratio': 2}]
```

Self and itemproduction are a OneToOneField relation.

ItemProduction.billOfMaterials() overrides Product.billOfMaterials()

```
def billOfMaterials(self):
    bom = self.inventoryItem.product.billOfMaterials()
    for x in bom:
        x.ratio = x.ratio * self.qty
    return bom
```

This basically takes a Product's Bill of Materials (recipe list) and figures the expected Bill of Materials for Production of n amount of a Product. 
Also, when i try to filter on bomitem, the resulting queryset has same improper values.

```
>>>>bomitem.get(component=x)
>>><BOM: Product One: 5>
```

Why this erratic behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the database is is what you see with `.values('ratio')`
If you want the value to be `x.ratio = x.ratio * self.qty`, you'll have to save that model instance into the database after it has been initialiazed with your Python code with the calculation

A better approach would be to use a different field, one for `ratio`, and one for the calculated values you need (and decide if you want to save them into the DB or calculate on the fly, unless required, it's usually better not to store any calculated fields, that way your data cannot be inconsistent in the DB)